# Why human hair is losing its color over time?

Tags: human-biology, hair

Human hair is losing its color over time, that's a known fact.

I would like to know why, meaning what biological processes are involved in this?

Also, is it part of the DNA somehow, i.e. the exact rate of losing the color is known when one is born?

Comment: *`Human hair is losing its color over time, that's a known fact.`* Is it? I know plenty of elderly people who still have dark hair.

Comment: @Matt none that I know of, and even they can't retain the original color, just might lose less color. Unless you have a link to some official post about it?

Comment: @rg255 thanks, I searched for "hair" and "color" key words, that one doesn't contain any mention of "color".